# response write dentro de response write

Tags: asp

Tenho um site em banco de dados (grava o código da página dentro da tabela), exemplo:

```
<html>
...
```

Esse código acima eu salvo em um campo dentro da tabela, e para exibir, faço normalmente e tudo vem direito, porém estou precisando do seguinte:

dentro do código tem por exemplo `h1 date() h1` (tirei o < e > porque aqui esta entendendo como título

resumo:

quando eu faço `<%=%>` é a mesma coisa que response.write, então como vou colocar essa variável dentro do código que já esta em banco?

já tentei de tudo quando é jeito e tudo o que eu coloco é impresso na tela exatamente como coloco, no exemplo acima, vem escrito na página exatamente isso, date() dentro do h1.

detalhado..

criei um banco de dados dentro de um outro dominio que tenho e nele criei uma tabela com campo longtext e dentro dele criei o seguinte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Login</title>

<body class="gray-bg">
<div><h1 class="logo-name"></h1></div>
<%=date()%> (aqui é onde já testei de tudo (risos)
</body>
</html>
... (página não esta completa, mas só foi para entender)
```

e dentro do dominio que quero a página criei o seguinte:

```
SQLLerDados = "select * FROM sisindex"
Set RSLerDados=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RSLerDados.Open SQLLerDados, objConnPagina

if RSLerDados.eof then
    response.End()
else
    codigoPagina = RSLerDados("codigoPagina")
    response.write codigoPagina
end if
Set RSLerDados = Nothing
response.End()
```

Ou seja, vai no meu banco de dados e pega a página para ser exibida, só que essa página é em ASP e tem comandos e funções nela e o response.write esta entendendo como texto independente de como eu coloco as variáveis ASP, entendeu? ou acha que não expliquei certo. Obrigado

Comment: Eu não entendi bem o seu caso de uso, mas [existe uma maneira de executar código arbitrário](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2(v=vs.84).aspx). Ela costuma ser recomendada, e com ressalvas, apenas para processar *templates*. O problema é que se tiver um código no seu BD que manda formatar o servidor – e usar esse método é abrir a porta para injetarem código no seu bd –, o simples acesso a uma página da web vai formatar seu servidor... ou coisa pior.

Comment: Como como abrir a porta para injetarem código no meu BD? poderia me dizer como alguém faria isso? assim eu posso prevenir... eu já tenho tratamento de SQL Injection.... mas será que seria só isso?

Comment: Eu não conheço os detalhes da sua aplicação para dar exemplos, mas se você for usar isso, use com muito cuidado, tenha certeza do que está sendo passado para a função. Se os seus próprios usuários puderem salvar dados no bd que depois serão interpretados como asp, eles mesmos são uma ameaça.

Comment: os usuários salvam dados, mas no BD deles (outro dominio), esse dominio que tem o bd dos códigos, será usado apenas para exibir o conteúdo da página... juro que fiquei confuso com o código, não sei se é porque estou desde as 5 da manha nisso kkk, mas será que poderia me dar uma luz nesse link que passou?

Answer (score 4):

Se for no corpo do HTML:

```
<h1><%= date() %></h1>
```

Se for concatenar *strings*:

```
Response.Write "<h1>" & date() & "</h1>"
```

Se seu código fonte está armazenado com funções no BD, é o caso de repensar na aplicação urgentemente. Normalmente isto não se justifica.

Uma solução seria um mini-sistema de templates:

```
Entrada = "<h1>$DATA$</h1>"  'os dados teriam que estar assim no DB
Saida = Replace( Entrada, "$DATA$", date() )
Response.Write Saida
```

Answer (score -1):

Ronaldo, infelizmente isso que vc quer fazer não é possível, pelo menos não diretamente assim. Tudo que você colocar dentro do Response.Write vai ser exibido como texto. O que estiver em formato de tag html será interpretada pelo navegador como html porque esse lê a página no próprio cliente. O ASP é processado pelo servidor e quando vc dá um Response.Write ou um <% = %> ele exibe o resultado do processamento ASP em formato de texto para o navegador conseguir interpretar normalmente.

Agora, eu não entendi muito a necessidade de armazenar as páginas em banco. Não é possível salvá-las como .asp mesmo?

Comment: Perdoe-me pela demora... o que realmente eu quero fazer é uma matriz de código, ou seja tenho 5 clientes que usam o mesmo sistema e para não ficar atualizando (quando houver necessidade) todas as páginas dos 5 dominios, eu queria atualizar apenas o código que esta no banco de dados e automaticamente tudo estaria ok.

Também poderia ser em xml, txt, mas ja tentei de tudo e a pagina não lê codigos ASP, simplesmente aparece como texto.

Alguém tem alguma dica para eu fazer isso? Obrigado